# Returning total values for a specific to a user when that user logs in

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

As the title says, I'm trying to get the specific data from a user when they are logged in and aggregating it all, then returning that aggregated data. I've tried using the `$match` function, but with no luck. The frustrating part is I am able to return all of the data successfully in an array of objects. To be more specific, the code below runs successfully and returns an array of objects:

```
const runs = await Run.find({ user: req.user.id })
```

However this code does not, it returns an empty array:

```
const cumulativeTotals = await Run.aggregate([
    { $match: { user: req.user.id } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        totalRunTime: { $sum: '$runTime' },
        avgRunTime: { $avg: '$runTime' },
        totalRunDistance: { $sum: '$runDistance' },
        avgRunDistance: { $avg: '$runDistance' },
        avgPace: { $avg: '$avgPace' },
        totalHeartRate: { $avg: '$avgHeartRate' },
        totalActiveCalories: { $sum: '$activeCalories' },
        averageActiveCalories: { $avg: '$activeCalories' },
        absoluteTotalCalories: { $sum: '$totalCalories' },
        avgTotalCalories: { $avg: '$totalCalories' },
      }
    }
  ])
```

And I am unsure as to why this is the case. What it should be returning is an array with an object that is populated with all the the aggregated data inside of it.

I also know that if I remove the `$match` it will successfully aggregate ALL of the data in the runs collection, so I think it has something to do with that.

Below is all the relevant code:

```
const getRuns = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const runs = await Run.find({ user: req.user.id })

  const cumulativeTotals = await Run.aggregate([
    { $match: { user: req.user.id } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        totalRunTime: { $sum: '$runTime' },
        avgRunTime: { $avg: '$runTime' },
        totalRunDistance: { $sum: '$runDistance' },
        avgRunDistance: { $avg: '$runDistance' },
        avgPace: { $avg: '$avgPace' },
        totalHeartRate: { $avg: '$avgHeartRate' },
        totalActiveCalories: { $sum: '$activeCalories' },
        averageActiveCalories: { $avg: '$activeCalories' },
        absoluteTotalCalories: { $sum: '$totalCalories' },
        avgTotalCalories: { $avg: '$totalCalories' },
      }
    }
  ])


  if (!runs) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'No Runs Found for This User' })
    return
  }

  const response = {
    runs,
    cumulativeTotals
  }

  res.status(200).json(response)
})
```

Comment: _"... this code does not ... [return] an array of objects ..."_ What does it return?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Added clarification that it should be returning an array with an object inside that contains all the aggregated data

Comment: And for that same `req.user.id`, `find` returns an array of objects?

Comment: @rickhg12hs that is correct, yes, but the array is populated with objects whose user key matches the user key specified elsewhere in the code. An API that connects the front end and back end

Comment: I'm a little confused by the qualifier, _"... specified elsewhere in the code ..."_.  In the code shown, does `console.log(runs);` show what you expect?

Comment: @rickhg12hs The response from the getRuns function in and of itself returns an object with two keys: `runs` and `cumulativeTotals`. On the front end, which is react, I have a setter which sets the data to what is returned by getRuns. So I would `console.log(runData.runs)`, and that would return the array of objects of each individual run that has been submitted by the user to the database. However, if I do `console.log(runData.cumulativeTotals)`, I get an empty array back, which should not be the case. It should be returning an array with an object with the cumulativeTotals in that object.

Comment: If you begin with `const id = req.user.id;` and then use `id` in both `find` and `aggregate`, what happens then?

Comment: @rickhg12hs same issue previously of where the cumulativeTotals array is an empty array

Comment: If you use `const cumulativeTotals = await Run.aggregate([ ... ]).toArray()`, what is returned then?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried that one earlier, and I get an error saying that `Run.aggregate([]).toArray() is not a function`. It's a confusing one, this problem, as everywhere I've looked, it seems to be the case that I'd just have to use `$match`

Comment: It is confusing, are you using `mongoose` or some other ODM/ORM?

Comment: ... if so, and `"user"` values are `ObjectId`s, `mongoose`, or some other ODM, may be casting the `req.user.id` string to an `ObjectId` in `find`, but not in `aggregate`.  You could trying casting/converting `req.user.id` to the proper type in `aggregate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253744/discussion-between-lofton-gentry-and-rickhg12hs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with the assistance of [rickhg12hs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409374/rickhg12hs), we were able to determine that the issue with `{match: { user: req.user.id } }` was that I was trying to compare a string to an ObjectId, which wouldn't work. This is because the API I set up returns the user id as a string, and not as an ObjectID. To make sure you're comparing the right value types, (in this case ObjectID), you can instead do:

```
{ $match: { user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id) } }
```

Which takes the returned string and turns it into a new ObjectID, and because it's now comparing ObjectIDs, it works.

It was in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#note) all along apparently, I just didn't look hard enough